# DevToolsActivePortfile not found/Chrome not reachable when using user-data-dir argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate cookie collection necessary for another use case outside the scope of this question. When I try to run my code, I get this error which only occurs when I use the `user-data-dir` and/or `profile-directory` arguments in options. First I would get `DevToolsActivePort not found` error, but after adding the `remote-debugging-port=8000` argument, I get `chrome not reachable` error.

Few things to note:

- Using the default built in browser (Microsoft Edge) is necessary
- The user must be signed in
- I want to run this in headless mode if possible
- Using `Edge` or `ChromiumEdge` class makes no difference at all

I tried running in headless mode, it doesn't give me any errors but with that, the user is not signed in to the Microsoft/Google account. I have already searched almost the entire internet but to no avail

My code (Using selenium in python):

```py
import time
import os

from selenium.webdriver import EdgeService
from selenium.webdriver import ChromiumEdge
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions

# service = EdgeService(r'assets\msedgedriver.exe')
# service.start()

options = EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") # an answer on stackoverflow which did not work
options.add_argument("remote-debugging-port=8000") # another one which did not work
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"

driver = ChromiumEdge(options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com")
# driver.get("https://bing.com")

driver.save_screenshot("ss2.png")
with open("cookies.txt", "w") as f:
    contents = ""
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    for cookie in cookies:
        contents += cookie.get('name') + ": " + cookie.get('value') + "\n"
    f.write(contents)
```

The error(s) I get (Pycharm console output running in administrator to ensure sufficient permissions):

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\project\test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = ChromiumEdge(options=options)
  File "C:\path\to\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\path\to\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\path\to\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\path\to\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "C:\path\to\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\path\to\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Microsoft Edge failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6149E2602+60402]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF614967352+253666]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF614739C99]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF614772FB2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61476D18B]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6147B423F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6147AB863]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61477C585]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61477B993]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF61477CD14]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF614BC34A4+1161924]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6147FE5F6]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6148BB083+37459]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6148B2C4D+3613]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF614BC21E4+1157124]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6149716A8+295480]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF61496CB74+276228]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF61496CCA2+276530]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF61495FA91+222753]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF6B647344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF6B7826B1+33]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Seems you are missing -- for arguments.

Comment: @Infern0 I tried it but it changes nothing. The only solution I found so far is to kill all running msedge.exe tasks and then run the driver